Moving large amount of data from Backblaze B2 to AWS S3 buckets
We have 20 TB data in Backblaze B2 storage. We want to migrate this to AWS S3 securely. What are my options for doing this in a scalable, secure way?

Can I do this without hitting the disk? (Cloud to cloud)? - Preferable
Are there any tools, or services available for the same? (3rd party)
Any programmatic options? (command line scripts etc.)


1st approch:
You can do it without hitting the disk.
There are tools that will do cloud to cloud transfer in secure way.
Try Rclone. Its open source and support both cloud platform that you mentioned.
And it is scalable as well because of multi thread support.
Command:
rclone copy b2:your-backblaze-bucket s3:your-aws-bucket --transfers 10 --checkers 20 --progress


rclone copy: Copies files from the source to the destination, ignoring unchanged files.
b2:your-backblaze-bucket: Specifies the Backblaze B2 bucket as the source.
s3:your-aws-bucket: Specifies destination path of the file inthe AWS S3 bucket.
--transfers 10: Set the no. of concurrent file transfers.
--checkers 20: Configures 20 concurrent file comparison processes for verification.
--progress: For realtime monitoring of progress.

2nd approch:
Using Backblaze's B2 Python SDK and boto3 for AWS

Thanks. Looks promising. I am assuming that in this case, both the source (Backblze B2 Bucket) and Destination (AWS S3 BUcket) have public access enabled during the transfer. If not, then how will the authentication work?

Public access won't be needed. In rclone first you have do the configuration where you have to provide authentication key for backblaze B2. And on Aws side authentication will be done using aws access and secret key.

Perfect. Thanks!
